# SQL Server stored procedure parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0, stored-procedures

I have a table with 2 columns-

- column "aa" - NOT NULL int
- column "bb" - NOT NULL int

I have a c# function which calls a stored procedure

```
...
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@aa", SqlDbType.Int));
cmd.Parameters["@aa"].Value = aaValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@bb", SqlDbType.Int));
cmd.Parameters["@bb"].Value = bbValue?? (object)DBNull.Value;
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); ...
```

Now I want the stored procedure to return all the entries which have "aa" equal to aaValue and "bb" equal to bbValue. but if bbValue is null, i want to return all the entries only with "aa" equal to aaValue.

How can I write such a stored procedure?

Here is what I have done, but it doesn't work

```
SELECT ID  
FROM MyTable 
WHERE aa = @aa AND (bb IS NULL OR bb = @bb)
```

Comment: ok, i found my mistake. instead of `bb is null` should be `@bb is null`

Answer (score 2):

For what it is worth, you will find this approach has suboptimal performance, this line (when corrected)

```
(@bb is null OR bb = @bb)
```

Means that any index on `bb` cannot be used, because at compile time it is not known whether or not `@bb` will be `NULL`, so a query plan that caters for both scenarios will be chosen. It would be better to separate your queries with and `IF/ELSE` flow operator, that way two plans can be cached, one for when `@bb` is `NULL` and one for when it isn't:

```
IF @bb IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT  ID  
    FROM    MyTable 
    WHERE   aa = @aa;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT  ID  
    FROM    MyTable 
    WHERE   aa = @aa
    AND     bb = @bb;
END
```

Comment: It's a good approach for performance but horribly to maintain if you got lots of conditions. I suggest a lecture on http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html#casestudy it also presents a few more thecniques to create conditional queries

Comment: This is a good article, but I felt it was over kill in this scenario so did not mention the alternatives when using a number of optional parameters since the question only mentions one conditional parameter. For one conditional parameter there is no reason not to use `IF/ELSE`, but yes, it may be worth a read for the OP should they extend their procedure to take more optional parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot the @ for the @bb variable since all you want is to check if the varibale, not the row value is null

```
SELECT ID  from MyTable where  aa = @aa and (@bb is null OR bb = @bb)
```